# Can't log in when browsing on a mobile device (full site theme)

Tags: bug, login

I've bben having problems logging in to SE for over a day now. I always try logging in with Facebook and end up with "No OpenID provided":

[image: Image to be added.]

Yet I am logged on to Facebook both on the app and on the browser. So what is wrong? Why can't I login?

**Edit**

I open a random SE site from mobile:

[image]

I tap log in, and:

[image]

I tap "log in via Facebook", and I get to the screen above.

**Update**

It appears only the default "Internet" browser gives this problem: I'm editing from my mobile with Firefox. I might consider switching, but still I'd like to know what is wrong with Internet communicating with SE...

**Update 2**
 (December 6, 2015)

I [pushed the matter "downstream" onto the Android site](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/130822/internet-browser-not-logging-in-to-se). Let us see what they have to say there.

Comment: That's not mobile web, this is the full site theme

Comment: @ShadowWizard does the image clarify? Anyway it means I am not logged in at all, and trying to log in, i.e. tapping "log in", the choosing "log in via Facebook", gives the result in the image.

Comment: When you open Facebook in the browser, are you logged in? Maybe you're logged in only via their app. (which SE on browser can't really identify)

Comment: @ShadowWizard among the 41 tabs currently open in my browser, there is one where my timeline is visible, and I'm clearly logged in. I don't think I could be logged in as someone else, so, yes, I am logged in.

Comment: So guess it is time to wait for a dev to look into it. When you browse from desktop computer can you log in?

Comment: Yes I can. But what do you mean by "full site theme"? See my (just made) edit before replying.

Comment: PS Android app won't offer image upload, so for now image implies computer :).

Comment: "full site" theme means you clicked the "full site" link in the footer, this is what you did in the first screenshot. To get back to mobile theme, click the "mobile" link in the footer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did _not_ click _any_ "full site" link. I only tapped "log in" and "log in from Facebook". It went to the full site theme by itself when I clicked "log in from Facebook". I thought the edit would have cleared that.

Comment: Also, clicking "mobile" in the footer from the first screenshot has **no effect whatsoever**.

Comment: OK, this doesn't really matter and probably not directly related to the bug. I was just explaining what I meant by "full site"

Comment: For the record, the problem persists.